# JavaScript run eval() with imported modules - or alternative?

Tags: javascript, import, module, jsfiddle

I am currently trying to build a "web IDE", similiar to e.g JSFiddle.

I want to execute user input (JavaScript) locally in the browser - which works fine.

For that I simply used

```
let userInput = `console.log("the user typed this")`
eval(userInput) // correctly executed the script from above
```

However, I want to access statically hosted modules as well - like `myModule.js`

```
export { test }
function test() {
   console.log("I am a module")
}
```

and let the user use that module like that

```
let userInput = `
  import { test } from "./myModule.js"
  test()
`
eval(userInput) // throws an error
```

which throws an error that `cannot use import outside a module`

now to my question(s):

1. Can I somehow use import() dynamically inside the eval() statement?
2. Is there perhaps an alternative that allows me to execute user input inside the browser with imported modules?

Note: I am using Vue (nuxt) for an easy UI

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use `fetch()` instead of using `import`?